# SemiDefiniteOptimization - The matrix is not symmetric error

Tags: matrix, mathematical-optimization

I get the following error,

> SemidefiniteOptimization::herm: The matrix {{0.00256497,0.00128248,0.00128248,0.00128248,0.00128248,2.42861*10^-17,6.93889*10^-18},{0.00128248,0.00128248,-0.0362029,-0.0372907,-0.00491249,-0.0577597,-0.00220394},<<3>>,{2.51535*10^-17,-0.0577597,-0.0409928,-0.14895,-0.0101405,0.00256497,-0.0263083},{6.93889*10^-18,-0.00220394,-0.00173376,-0.0425018,0.0177934,-0.0263083,0.00256497}} is not Hermitian or real and symmetric.

This is the same matrix,

```
m={{0.00256497, 0.00128248, 0.00128248, 0.00128248, 0.00128248, 
  2.42861*10^-17, 6.93889*10^-18}, {0.00128248, 
  0.00128248, -0.0362029, -0.0372907, -0.00491249, -0.0577597, \
-0.00220394}, {0.00128248, -0.0362029, 
  0.00128248, -0.0399526, -0.037901, -0.0409928, -0.00173376}, \
{0.00128248, -0.0372907, -0.0399526, 
  0.00128248, -0.0621704, -0.14895, -0.0425018}, {0.00128248, \
-0.00491249, -0.037901, -0.0621704, 0.00128248, -0.0101405, 
  0.0177934}, {2.51535*10^-17, -0.0577597, -0.0409928, -0.14895, \
-0.0101405, 
  0.00256497, -0.0263083}, {6.93889*10^-18, -0.00220394, -0.00173376, \
-0.0425018, 0.0177934, -0.0263083, 0.00256497}}
```

which is clearly symmetric.

I tried setting the tolerance parameter for `SemiDefinteOptimization` but it didnt work.

Comment: So it is not exactly symmetric, for example entry $(1,6)$ is `2.42861*10^-17` but entry $(6,1)$ is `2.51535*10^-17`. What about working with `mSymmetric = (m+Transpose[m])/2` to correct the small numerical discrepancies?

Comment: The very small non symmetric part of you matrix is presumably the result of numerical errors of machine numbers. You can easily getting rid of it by using "Chop".